# Writing a program to find the largest in a series of numbers.

Tags: c, scanf

I am very new to C. I am using A modern Approach to C programming by King 2nd Edition.

I am stuck on chapter 6. Question 1: Write a program that finds the largest in a series of numbers entered by the user. The program must prompt the user to enter the numbers one by one. When the user enters 0 or a negative number, the program must display the largest non negative number entered.

So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
float a, max, b; 

for (a == max; a != 0; a++) {
printf("Enter number:");
scanf("%f", &a);
}

printf("Largest non negative number: %f", max);

return 0;
}
```

I do not understand the last part of the question, which is how to see which non-negative number is the greatest at the end of user input of the loop.

```
max = a > a ???
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you expect `for (a == max; a != 0; a++)` to do?

Comment: The question wants you to stop as soon as user enters a negative number (or zero) and print the largest of the numbers entered till now.  BTW, your program is buggy as max is not initialized and no comparison/reassignment of max inside the for loop.

Comment: Luchian, I was labeling a to max for the end part.

Comment: Then testing a did not equal 0. I then thought I could try to increment a to the next letter for the max testing phase at the end?

Comment: @caelan: Your `for` loop makes no sense. The `a == max` part compares `a` to `max` (both of which are uninitialized) and does nothing where you have it - that part of the `for` is used to perform initialization; you aren't initializing anything. The next part, `a != 0`, will cause undefined behavior because `a` is uninitialized - who knows what value it holds? Your loop may never run, if `a` happens to be `0`.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to update max if a is greater than it each iteration thru the loop, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float max = 0, a;

    do{
        printf("Enter number:");

        /* the space in front of the %f causes scanf to skip
         * any whitespace. We check the return value to see
         * whether something was *actually* read before we
         * continue.
         */

        if(scanf(" %f", &a) == 1) {
            if(a > max){
                max = a;
            }
        }

        /* We could have combined the two if's above like this */
        /* if((scanf(" %f", &a) == 1) && (a > max)) {
         *     max = a;
         * }
         */
    }
    while(a > 0);

   printf("Largest non negative number: %f", max);

   return 0;
}
```

Then you simply print max at the end.
A do while loop is a better choice here because it needs to run at least once.

Comment: Silly code-gremlins. I've deleted my other comment. This is a good effort, but you should really check the return value from `scanf` to ensure that something was *actually* read.

Comment: @NikBougalis Probably should check it, but this is just a simple problem. TBH, I'm not terribly familiar with how to error handle in C.

Comment: I tweaked your post to check for the error and properly skip whitespace, along with some comments. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Minor point: Recommend initializing "a" with 0.0.  Without doing so, should the first scanf try to read junk, the while (a>0) would operate on uninitialized "a".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float enter_num,proc=0;

    for(;;)
    {
       printf("Enter the number:");
       scanf("%f",&enter_num);


       if(enter_num == 0)
       {
           break;
       }

       if(enter_num < 0)
       {
           proc>enter_num;
           proc=enter_num;
       }

       if(proc < enter_num)
       {
           proc = enter_num;
       }

    }

    printf("Largest number from the above is:%.1f",proc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't exit on numbers < 0, and the corresponding if is really strange!